# AWS SAM Python debug on Mac M1 (Apple Silicon)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, apple-m1

I'm currently working with AWS Lambdas functions with Python code. There is an interesting feature while working with them that allows users to debug Lambda functions locally.

When debugging locally the function is ran within a docker image. While trying to build images in M1 Mac I always have problems.

I'm currently trying to debug the Python Lambda function and got this error:

```
Validate Docker has failed: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory7 has failed: Cannot run program "docker": error=2, No such file or directory
```

Probably it is related to ARM64 architecture and Docker.

> Anyone knows any workaround in order to debug Python Lambdas locally
> in Mac M1?

Comment: Do you have Docker installed on your Mac?

Comment: Well, I re-installed Docker, now with the proper Mac M1 Apple Silicon installation and got some advances. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**Solved**:

The error was because I had installed Docker for Mac Intel version.

Install Docker with steps recommended by the documentation in [this](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/install/) link. Be sure that you are installing the Apple Silicon version.

Also before installing it, it is recommended to install Rosseta 2 in your Mac M1 Apple Silicon.

```
$ softwareupdate --install-rosetta
```

Also in [this](https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/apple-silicon/) page there are some common issues and troubleshoots for Docker in Mac M1 Apple Silicon.