# AWS SAM CLI on Mac OS build does not work - cannot find docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, aws-lambda, aws-sam-cli

I'm trying to run `sam build` using the AWS SAM CLI, but run into a problem. I get the following error:

```bash
Build Failed
Error: Building image for DefaultFunction requires Docker. is Docker running?
```

It looks like docker cannot be found, although it is installed. When I run `docker ps` I see the confirmation that Docker is running. The weird thing is that the `build` command does actually work for my colleagues in the same project who are also using MacOS with Intel chip.

I have `SAM CLI, version 1.60.0` installed

I have `Docker version 20.10.20` installed and running

I'm running it on `MacOS Montery 12.5`

I've been looking for a answer to this problem for a while now, but couldn't find a solution. Does anyone know how to fix this? I've followed all steps from [this documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-cli-install-mac.html).

Comment: Looks like duplicate of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72438222/aws-sam-python-debug-on-mac-m1-apple-silicon

Comment: It's not really a duplicate, that one is about a Mac with M1 Silicon - I'm having Mac with Intel chip

Comment: Related to this issue on Github - https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4329#issuecomment-1289588827

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is due to certain recent versions of Docker for Mac breaking compatibility. Check this [bug report](https://github.com/aws/aws-sam-cli/issues/4329#issuecomment-1289588827). Apparently it has already been fixed in the latest version of Docker for Mac.

In the meantime, the following workaround (as specified in the above GitHub issue) works for me:

```bash
DOCKER_HOST=unix://$HOME/.docker/run/docker.sock sam local start-api
```

Comment: For colima it is `DOCKER_HOST=unix://$HOME/.colima/default/docker.sock`. From their docs at https://github.com/abiosoft/colima/blob/main/docs/FAQ.md#docker-socket-location.